# converting an analogue signal to be viewed on a 7 segment display

Tags: digital-logic, analog, converter, 7segmentdisplay

How do I convert an analogue signal to a digital signal and display it on 7 segment LED's. This must be done without using any programmable micro-controllers. 
It's for a school project. The analogue input signal is coming from another unit which monitors the room temperature.

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: It looks like. Ok, no MCU. Use a CPLD and an ADC instead ;-)

Comment: Just get a digital multimeter and save yourself the hassle of designing something with weird constraints.

Comment: If it is homework, then I expect the correct answer would be: implement a simple ADC with parallel output, then use a pile of discrete logic ICs to take in the binary bits and drive the LED display.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You use a digital voltmeter chip such as the [Intersil ICL7107](http://www.intersil.com/content/dam/intersil/documents/icl7/icl7106-07-07s.pdf).

[image]

*Figure 1. Intersil 7106/7 voltmeter.*

Comment: Preassembled modules based on this kind of chip are readily available, too.